# CS1502 error when inserting media url in img source attribute (Umbraco)

Tags: html, image, razor, compiler-errors, umbraco

I want to display a header logo on my master template.

So far I have this code:

```
<h1 class="brand_name">
    <a href="/"><img width="320px" 
       src='@(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>
       ("headerLogo").Url)'>
    </a>
</h1>
```

When i run the page i receive this error message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1bZT.png

I'm not sure what causes this error, as the formatting looks fine to me. The mediapicker property editor for the header logo is defined in a language document type, which has the master as its template.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling GetPropertyValue to try to return an IEnumerable of IPublishedContent, yet you immediately try to use a single .Url. Have you tried Model.Content.GetPropertyValue ("headerLogo").Url instead?

Comment: I put the code in a partial view instead. When i run this code, i get the same error: @item.GetPropertyValue("headerLogo").Url

Answer (score 0):

If using a MediaPicker, I've been successful in using it in an img tag with the following:

```
@var image = Umbraco.Media(Convert.ToString(Umbraco.Field("mediaPickerName"))).umbracoFile;
<img src="@image" />
```